# Convert 'yyyymmdd hhmmss' to 'mm/dd/yy hh:mm'

Tags: vba, excel, datetime, timestamp

I have a row of data (Cell A3 and down) that contains a Unix timestamp in `yyyymmdd hhmmss` format that I'm trying to convert to `mm/dd/yy hh:mm` format *automatically*.

The code I have so far works when I have the data starting in cell A1, but I need A1 to remain blank, therefore the data starts at A2. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGgIL.png) is an example screenshot of column A:

[image: an example screenshot of column A]

```
Sub auto_open()
'
' auto_open Macro
'

'
ChDir "C:\"
Workbooks.Open      Filename:="C:\Users\username\Desktop\file1.csv"
Intersect(Sheets("file1").Range("A:EW"),     Sheets("file1").UsedRange).Copy     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Golden").Range("A2")
Windows("file1.csv").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = False

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As String
Dim z As String
Dim w As String

NumRows = Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row

Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Activate
For x = 2 To NumRows
     z = Cells(x, 1).Value
     y = Mid(z, 5, 2) & "/" & Mid(z, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(z, 4)
     w = Mid(z, 10, 2) & ":" & Mid(z, 12, 2) & ":" & Mid(z, 14, 2)
     y = y + TimeValue(w)
     Cells(x, 1).Value = y
Next x

Range("A3").Select

End Sub
```

It errors whether I set the range to A2 or A3 and down.

Does anyone have recommendations?

Debug highlights `y = Mid(z, 5, 2) & "/" & Mid(z, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(z, 4)` but I'm not sure what the problem is.

Format cells (custom > `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`) also does not work in my case, unfortunately.

Comment: What error do you get?  Change `z` to a `Range` and try `z = Cells(x,1)` and then see if it works.  That might be the quickest fix.

Comment: Runtime error 13: Type mismatch

Comment: With the method you are using you will not get to the last rows.  You have numrows counting the number of rows in a range. lets say the last row of your data is on row 20 numrows will equal 18, then when passed into the for loop you will only go to row 18 not 20.  Change to `numRows = Range("A3").end(xlDown).Row`  This will, in  the instance here give you the 20.  Then your for loop will go from 3 to NumRows.  This is not your problem but will be a problem later.

Comment: Changed 'dim z as string' to 'dim z as range' and changed z=Cells(x,1) - gives runtime error 91, object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: try dateserial(mid1,mid2,mid3) or setting y to a string

Comment: Hm, this is odd. Your macro works for me fine (except the last row, see @ScottCraner's comment). Do you have more of this macro that you're not showing? Perhaps it's something to do with that. And  yeah, sorry, I just also realized changing to `Range` isn't the quick fix I hoped

Comment: Change y to string. then when you assign it to the cell  use cdate(Y & w)

Comment: Also, does it *always* give you this error? Or does it work sometimes, and other times it gives you this error?

Comment: Sorry the posting to the cell should have a space added, `cdate(y & " " & w)`

Comment: See my original post for the entire code im using. It errors every time. I followed @ScottCraner advice but it still errors.

Comment: Methinks it might have to do with the sheet and active cells.  Step through your code, and when it sets `z`, hover your mouse over the variable name to see what's being stored. Is it the correct text?  If you copy just the part that loops and fixes the text into a new workbook and run it, does it still give you an error?  After you declare `y, z, and w` add `Dim ws as Worksheet`, then `Set ws = ActiveSheet`, then edit `NumRows = Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row` to `NumRows = ws.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row` and finally, ` z = ws.Cells(x, 1).Value`.

Comment: The code works fine given that the data is in A1. The below answer by @SHG worked. Thanks Everyone.

Comment: Just for your information the last part that was missing is the fact you wanted to start your loop at 3 not two.

Comment: @BruceWayne that was never going to work because `z = Cells(x,1)` is missing `Set`. Explains the error OP got after trying

Comment: @Brad - d'oh! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it with no looping at all:

```
Sub kyle()
    With [a3].Resize([a1048576].End(xlUp).Row - 2)
        .Value = Evaluate("transpose(transpose(DATE(MID(" & .Address & ",1,4),MID(" & .Address & ",5,2),MID(" & .Address & ",7,2)) + TIME(MID(" & .Address & ",10,2),MID(" & .Address & ",12,2),MID(" & .Address & ",14,2))))")
    End With
End Sub
```

Note: you can then use whatever number formatting for the dates you please.

Comment: I had a feeling you'd use []. Nice use of Evaluate.

Comment: <Sarcasm>Swoops in here with his, "I can do it in one step, no loops."  While the rest of us peons are still stuck in the dark ages...mumble...mumble</Sarcasm>.  I really need to start thinking in this manner, it would save so much time in my coding.

Comment: @ScottCraner If you like to work with array formulas, you can make a lot of hay with Evaluate() from VBA.  ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, I don't like them and have avoided using them till now.  I am finally seeing the benefit of them.  Doubt I will ever be at your level but I am learning.

Comment: @ScottCraner All it takes is practice.

Comment: Or      .Value = Evaluate("if(row(), --text(substitute(" & .Address & ", "" "", """"), ""0000-00-00 00\:00\:00""))")

Comment: I tried @ExcelHero's code and get "Runtime error 424 Object required" - it highlights `With [a3].Resize([a1048576].End(xlUp).Row - 2)`

Comment: @KyleL Are you running Excel 2003?

Comment: @ExcelHero - excel 2010

Comment: Ill have to remove some data / code as some of its confidential. Ill send it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub Kyle()
  Dim cell As Range

  ThisWorkbook.Activate

  For Each cell In Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    If cell.Value Like "######## ######" Then
      cell.Value = CDate(Format(cell.Value, "@@@@-@@-@@@@@:@@:@@"))
    End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

Then format the column however you prefer.

For me, that converts

20150904 213613
20150124 194003
20150404 163056
20151220 100509
20150510 213512

to this:

09/04/2015 21:36
01/24/2015 19:40
04/04/2015 16:30
12/20/2015 10:05
05/10/2015 21:35

Comment: This works great, Thank you very much. It leaves me at the end of the sheet though, is there anyone it could leave me at the top?

Comment: @KyleL - At the end (just before `End Sub`) add `Cells(1,1).Select`.

Comment: I like this method because it is more readable and maintainable than a series of MID() functions.

Answer (score 0):

@ExcelHero answered my question via email. The following is the working code for anyone who needs future reference.

```
    With [a3].Resize([a65536].End(xlUp).Row - 2)
    If Len(.Item(1)) = 15 Then
        .Value = Evaluate("transpose(transpose(DATE(MID(" & .Address & ",1,4),MID(" & .Address & ",5,2),MID(" & .Address & ",7,2)) + TIME(MID(" & .Address & ",10,2),MID(" & .Address & ",12,2),MID(" & .Address & ",14,2))))")
    End If
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
End With
```